# How to fix error C2679 in template class that is used for returning different types based on parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a template function that has a generic type as the return type. The purpose of the function is to initialize a type and assign some values on it. The type is specified by an int variable in the parameter. For some reason, whenever I call this function, I get the error:

> Error C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'B' (or there is no acceptable conversion).

The line the error occurs depends on if I specify 0 or 1 as the parameter.

Here is an example of what the code looks like:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
    int value;
};

class B
{
public:
    B();
    ~B();
    long long value;
};

template<typename T>
T Load(int const &tp)
{
    T item;

    switch (tp)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            A a = A();
            a.value = 10;
            //... Load file from hard disk and initialize it to this class.
            item = a; //Error if parameter is 1
        }
        break;
        case 1:
        {
            B b = B();
            b.value = 20;
            //... Load different file from hard disk and initialize it to 
            //this class.
            item = B(); //Error if parameter is 0
        }
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    A a = Load<A>(0);
}
```

Do you know how to fix this error?

Comment: There's no common type between `A` and `B`. Thus, `T` cannot have any specific type.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix? I already tried making them both inherit from a base class but it gives the same error...

Comment: Why do you need the switch statement?

Comment: In order to assign the correct type to the generic variable and perform the correct actions.

Comment: Let me rephrase: what's the use case for this? (Why can't you just write `A a = Load<A>();`?)

Comment: Oh, the real use is basically, im going to have different classes that will contain different file types, the function basically specifies the type of file to load and the switch will initialize the specified type and then return it. Let me edit the code actually to make this more clear...

Comment: So, for instance, `A` corresponds to a `.txt` file and `B` corresponds to `.png` file?

Comment: It's not possible to suggest a generic solution to this because the solution depends on your specific application. **What are you going to do with `A` and `B`?**

Comment: Load different types of files from the hard disk... A is supposed to be one type, and B is supposed to be another. The template function is supposed to be here so I don't have separate functions for loading different file types.

Answer (score 1):

Is there something you're not showing? The fact that it's a class template means `item` just needs to be a type having a `value` member - you don't need to be explicit about the intended type. I think you're wanting this:

```
template<typename T>
T Load(int tp)
{
    T item;

    switch (tp)
        {
        case 0:
            item.value = 10;
            break;
        case 1:
            item.value = 20;
            break;
        }

    return item;
}

A a = Load<A>(0);
B b = Load<B>(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no common type between `A` and `B`. Thus, `T` cannot have any specific type.

Let's put ourselves in the compiler's shoes. How do we figure out what `T` is?

Let's try `T = A`. This fails when we try to do this:

```
T item = B();
```

Similarly, `T = B` fails when we try to do this:

```
T item = A();
```

Unfortunately, we can't explicitly create a type that works with both `A` and `B`, since they share no common ground.

---

Since you mentioned that `A` and `B` correspond to different file types, let me suggest a solution:

```
switch(filetype) {
case FILETYPE_A:
    a = A::Load(filename);
    print << a.text << std::endl;  // do stuff with a
    break;
case FILETYPE_B:
    b = A::Load(filename);
    b.show_image();  // do stuff with b
    break;
};
```

This is simpler than creating a generic container for the different files. Creating a generic container means you are severely restricted to only *common* operations that can be performed on all files.

As shown in the example above, they do not share the same capabilities (one is text and the other is an image). Unless you can define a **common interface** between these files, it simply does not make sense to have a generic type.

If you truly want some sort of generic solution you may consider either:

- A common **interface** class that `A` and `B` inherit from
- Adapter pattern

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. So basically there is no way for this to be done? Let's say for example, you have a template function that takes the class as a generic type, and in the parameter a directory, and you have different types of classes for different file types. Like A goes with "a.TYPE1" and B goes with "b.TYPE2". And you want in one instance to load file type "TYPE1" into class a. Is there a way to have one template function for this or do I have to break this down into different functions for different types?